# File upload with Rails 4 and Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, paperclip

This is probably a simple (?) fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm working on a Rails site and am nearly finished. I have a form that includes a file upload field (using Paperclip). To customize, I'm following [this guide](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/).

I have it setup, but when i select a file, the filename is not being displayed. Here is the relevant bit of code from my site:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <span class="btn btn-file">Upload an image<%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %></span>
    </span>
    <%= f.text_field :image, class: "form-control", :class => "input-field", readonly: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS (currently) matches what's in the above-linked guide. I assume I need to change `:image` in `f.text_field` to something else, but I can't figure it out. Maybe it's a security thing.